# How can I add a collider/s to a line renderer circle?

Tags: unity, c#

With this code I can create a circle using LineRenderer and control in both editor mode and run time mode on the drawn circle properties like radius and width and height.

Now I want to add to this circle a collider not a box collider but a collider on the circle it self only on the drawn part/s. but not to create many colliders for each position. I could create a lot of colliders and position them on the circle positions but I'm looking for a better performance way if there is any.

And also when I'm changing the circle properties like width or height change the collider width and height too.

So if some object/s touch/reach the line do something.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
 
[ExecuteAlways]
[RequireComponent(typeof(UnityEngine.LineRenderer))]
public class DrawCircle : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject centerObject;
    [Range(1, 50)] public int segments = 50;
    [Range(1, 5)] public float xRadius = 5;
    [Range(1, 5)] public float yRadius = 5;
    [Range(0.1f, 5)] public float width = 0.1f;
    [Range(0, 100)] public float height = 0;
    public bool controlBothXradiusYradius = false;
    public bool draw = true;
 
    [SerializeField] private LineRenderer line;
 
    private void Start()
    {
        if (!line) line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
 
        if (draw)
            CreatePoints();
    }
 
    public void CreatePoints()
    {
        line.enabled = true;
        line.widthMultiplier = width;
        line.useWorldSpace = false;
        line.widthMultiplier = width;
        line.positionCount = segments + 1;
 
        float x;
        float y;
 
        var angle = 20f;
        var points = new Vector3[segments + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < segments + 1; i++)
        {
            x = Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * xRadius;
            y = Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * yRadius;
 
            points[i] = new Vector3(x, height, y);
 
            angle += (380f / segments);
        }
 
        // it's way more efficient to do this in one go!
        line.SetPositions(points);
    }
 
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    private float prevXRadius, prevYRadius;
    private int prevSegments;
    private float prevWidth;
    private float prevHeight;
 
    private void OnValidate()
    {
        // Can't set up our line if the user hasn't connected it yet.
        if (!line) line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        if (!line) return;
 
        if (!draw)
        {
            // instead simply disable the component
            line.enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            // Otherwise re-enable the component
            // This will simply re-use the previously created points
            line.enabled = true;
 
            if (xRadius != prevXRadius || yRadius != prevYRadius || segments != prevSegments || width != prevWidth || height != prevHeight)
            {
                CreatePoints();
 
                // Cache our most recently used values.
                prevXRadius = xRadius;
                prevYRadius = yRadius;
                prevSegments = segments;
                prevWidth = width;
                prevHeight = height;
            }
 
            if (controlBothXradiusYradius)
            {
                yRadius = xRadius;
            }
        }
    }
#endif
}
```

I tried this but it's just adding an empty child game object to the empty gameobject this script is attached to and the child empty gameobject have a box collider.

but the player can still move through the circle.

I added the method AddCollider :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[ExecuteAlways]
[RequireComponent(typeof(UnityEngine.LineRenderer))]
public class DrawCircle : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject centerObject;
    [Range(1, 50)] public int segments = 50;
    [Range(1, 500)] public float xRadius = 5;
    [Range(1, 500)] public float yRadius = 5;
    [Range(0.1f, 5)] public float width = 0.1f;
    [Range(0, 100)] public float height = 0;
    public bool controlBothXradiusYradius = false;
    public bool draw = true;

    private Vector3 startPos;
    private Vector3 endPos;
    private Vector3[] positions;

    [SerializeField] private LineRenderer line;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (!line) line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

        

        if (draw)
            CreatePoints();

        startPos = line.GetPosition(0);
        endPos = line.GetPosition(line.positionCount - 1);

        AddCollider();
    }

    public void CreatePoints()
    {
        line.enabled = true;
        line.widthMultiplier = width;
        line.useWorldSpace = false;
        line.widthMultiplier = width;
        line.positionCount = segments + 1;

        float x;
        float y;

        var angle = 20f;
        var points = new Vector3[segments + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < segments + 1; i++)
        {
            x = Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * xRadius;
            y = Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * yRadius;

            points[i] = new Vector3(x, height, y);

            angle += (380f / segments);
        }

        // it's way more efficient to do this in one go!
        line.SetPositions(points);
    }

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    private float prevXRadius, prevYRadius;
    private int prevSegments;
    private float prevWidth;
    private float prevHeight;

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        // Can't set up our line if the user hasn't connected it yet.
        if (!line) line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        if (!line) return;

        if (!draw)
        {
            // instead simply disable the component
            line.enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            // Otherwise re-enable the component
            // This will simply re-use the previously created points
            line.enabled = true;

            if (xRadius != prevXRadius || yRadius != prevYRadius || segments != prevSegments || width != prevWidth || height != prevHeight)
            {
                CreatePoints();

                // Cache our most recently used values.
                prevXRadius = xRadius;
                prevYRadius = yRadius;
                prevSegments = segments;
                prevWidth = width;
                prevHeight = height;
            }

            if (controlBothXradiusYradius)
            {
                yRadius = xRadius;
            }
        }
    }
#endif

    private void AddCollider()
    {
        BoxCollider col = new GameObject("Collider").AddComponent<BoxCollider>();
        col.transform.parent = line.transform; // Collider is added as child object of line
        float lineLength = Vector3.Distance(startPos, endPos); // length of line
        col.size = new Vector3(lineLength, 0.1f, 1f); // size of collider is set where X is length of line, Y is width of line, Z will be set as per requirement
        Vector3 midPoint = (startPos + endPos) / 2;
        col.transform.position = midPoint; // setting position of collider object
        // Following lines calculate the angle between startPos and endPos
        float angle = (Mathf.Abs(startPos.y - endPos.y) / Mathf.Abs(startPos.x - endPos.x));
        if ((startPos.y < endPos.y && startPos.x > endPos.x) || (endPos.y < startPos.y && endPos.x > startPos.x))
        {
            angle *= -1;
        }
        angle = Mathf.Rad2Deg * Mathf.Atan(angle);
        col.transform.Rotate(0, 0, angle);
    }
}
```

This is the player components screenshots :

[image: Player components]

And the Draw Circle gameobject screenshot :

I changed the Draw Circle object position on the Y so the player will be able to move to it collide with it.

[image: circle]

What I want is that when the player is walking and get to the drawn circle no matter what direction the player will stop or do something but the idea is to detect when the player is getting to the drawn circle.

The idea is to use the circle the drawn circle as a border that will limit the player from keep moving any further far depending on what object the circle is around in this case the big space ship.

And because the big spaceship shape is not equal like a square I think using this circle is a good idea I can change the circle and set it as a border for all directions.

I don't mind if in some places the distance is not the same I'm not sure if it's possible to make something with equal distance from all sides of the circle but the idea is to use the circle for a border.

Comment: Presumably you tried adding a CircleCollider2D or PolygonCollider2D to your object and updating its parameters whenever you change your drawn line? Where specifically did you run into difficulty making that work?

Comment: @DMGregory I tried this in the Start for testing : line.transform.gameObject.AddComponent<CircleCollider2D>(); but the player still can go through the circle.  The player have a Rigidbody and a capsue collider the DRawCircle script is attached to empty gameobject.

Comment: Those look like details that belong in your question. You're not expecting a (3D) Rigidbody to interact with a (2D) CircleCollider2D, are you?

Comment: @DMGregory Updated my question with what I tried so far.

Comment: It's unclear to me whether you're using a 2D or 3D Rigidbody, or how you're moving your player. It's entirely possible the problem is there, not in how you're generating your collider.

Comment: @DMGregory The rigidbody is 3d and I'm moving the player with the unity Third Person User Control and Third Person Character using the wsad keys. I will add two screenshots of the player components and the drawcircle gameobject.